# In python how can you select the integer that closest to 0?

Tags: python, for-loop

list [1,2,3,4,5,6]

How would you write a line or lines of code that could sort through the list and find the value closest to 0?

Comment: what have you attempted? `for` loop?

Comment: Do you need to properly handle negative values?

Comment: no negative values

Comment: The term you are looking for is *minimum* which is provided by the [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#min) function.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about negative numbers use [min](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min):

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> min(arr)
1
```